# How to figure out whether an AJAX call in a function returns an error or succeeds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How would I detect whether an AJAX call in a function succeeds or fails? Let's say I call that function elsewhere.

**file.js**

```
function doSmallThing(param1, param2) {

 $.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   url: 'some_url',
   dataType: 'json',
   ...
   success: function (result) {

     // doStuff, signal that this code block is reached

   },

   error: function (error) {
     // signal that this is reached
   }

 })

}
```

**file2.js**

```
import File from "..location/of/file.js";

class SomeComponent extends React.Component {

  doSomething() {

    // stuck here

    if (File.doSmallThing(param1, param2) does not throw an error) {
       doMoreThings();
    } else {
       // do nothing
    }



  }

}
```

How would I detect the outcome of:

```
File.doSmallThing(param1, param2)
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: look at jquery Promise https://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: You could pass in a callback function into `doSmallThing` such as `doSmallThing(param1, param2, functionOnSuccess, functionOnFail)`, then call `functionOnSuccess()` when the Ajax request succeeds and fail if it fails. This will loop the control flow back into the file2.js.

Comment: Instead of having an if wrapping doMoreThings based on whether or not doSmallThing succeeded, you would set doMoreThings as the success callback of the ajax function

Comment: You return the promise that `$.ajax` returns and let the caller attach success and error callbacks: `doSmallThing(...).done(function() { }).fail(function() { })`. Check out the `$.ajax` docs: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and the jQuery tutorial: https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/ .

Answer (score 0):

Since you doing an Assincronous call, you dont know the outcome of

```
File.doSmallThing(param1, param2)
```

after its executed, acctually, the ajax call have not even finished by the time you reach the next line.

I would review how you are building your code. Begin by asking youself WHY you must know if there was an error. All error treatment shoud be done inside

```
error: function (error) {
   // signal that this is reached
}
```

If all else fails, you can pass an callback function and/or set a flag.